# How can i run a curl command in bash without syntax errors?

Tags: bash, curl

I am running the following in bash:

```
  read -p "Server: " SERVER
  read -p "Username: " NAME
  read -p "UserPassword: " USERPASSWORD
  curl -s -u ${NAME}:${USERPASSWORD} http://<REMOTE_SERVER_DETAILS>
  if [ $http_response != "200" ] then
     echo "Error" 
  else
    echo "Created Successfully."    
 fi
```

The curl command runs successfully . All i want to output to the user is the status , ie the http response header , but it gives an error

```
  syntax error near unexpected token `else'
```

Any ideas as to why this is giving syntax error?
Also can i output the error ?

Comment: `then` (like `else` and `fi`) is syntactically a statement on its own.You need a statement separator to the previous command. BTW, quoting the literal `200` is unnecessary, but `$http_response` should better be quoted.

Answer (score 0):

Two solutions: extra semicolon or line break afer `]`.

```
if [ "$http_response" != "200" ]; then

if [ "$http_response" != "200" ]
then
```

Comment: made the change , now says  !=: unary operator expected

Comment: or can i just ouptut the https header response instead and nothing else ?

Comment: @Tracey; You have to quote `$http_response` to avoid **this** syntax error. The variable is empty. I think you forgot to set it. At least in the fragment of the code you posted, I don't see an assignment to this variable.

Comment: @JoopEggen : Please quote the variable ....

Comment: @user1934428 I oversaw that having encountered the error once a long time ago. Thanks